# How to know which Magento Connect account was used to buy a particular extension?

Tags: extensions, magento-connect

I have taken over running a Magento project and there are several paid extensions that were downloaded at some point. How can I find out which Magento Connect account was used to download them? I need to find out what e-mail address was used to buy them so I can manage the upgrade process.

Normally I would expect to see an XML file somewhere in /downloads or something, that would list the associated account that was used to originally download the extension. Or something like that. But I've been looking and I haven't been able to find anything like that. Ideas?

How do I know what Magento Connect account was used to buy our extensions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Afaik you can't buy any extension on magento connect? I thought, you are redirected to the vendors shop, every time you buy an extension?

So whatever you bought, it is an account associated to the vendors shop, I think...

(but I never use magento connect, so I might be wrong)